# C Is it possible to use a value as an enum name?

Tags: c, enums

```
enum dice { 9=1, 10, J, Q, K, A };
```

Is it possible to use a value as an constant name?
Or do ive to write it out?

Comment: How would you expect the compiler to know when you meant `9` as the actual number v `9` as the enum? So, no

Comment: How would you use it? Why would you use it  `enum dice a = 9;` -> now `a == 1` ??

Comment: @PhilM Presumably `dice.9`  I don't see why this would be considered a dumb question on an absolute scale.

Comment: @HostileFork that works if C uses enum that way, but in C enum values are used as global barewords instead of within the enum namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name and members of an `enum` must conform to the rules governing all other identifiers, which are outlined in the C standard [§ 6.4.2, Identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2). An identifier cannot *be* a digit, nor may it *start with* a digit, but it may contain digits elsewhere.

Comment: It was done more as a courtesy to the Author. If your saying just skip it. That's fine.